# Dust.js template rendering with Backbone.LayoutManager

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, coffeescript

Let me elaborate on my setup:
I have precompiled dust.js templates that I would like to use with Backbone.LayoutManager.

Backbone.LayoutManager uses the following configuration:

```
Backbone.LayoutManager.configure
  manage: true
  fetch: (name) ->
    name
```

So the name of the template is passed through fetch straight to render, and I'd like to override render like this:

```
render: (template, context) ->
  done = @async
  dust.render @template, context, (err, out) ->
    throw err if err
    done(out)
```

But I cannot do this with render (presumably because the LayoutManager author assumed that template rendering would be synch).

Does anyone know how I could accomplish this?

Comment: Hey guys, just a quick update on this. Backbone LayoutManager supports asynchronous rendering of templates as of v0.7.1 :)

https://github.com/tbranyen/backbone.layoutmanager/commit/a181262a0f5eb5219ab814eb7c99a68944af1b44

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll need to modify the LayoutManger to handle asynchronous rendering of templates.

One of the ways to do this is to use the jQuery Deferred object where the call to `render` returns an instance of a `Deferred` object, which you then resolve in the call to the `Dust` library.

Then, modify Backbone.LayoutManager to NOT continue doing what it wants to with the templates until that Deferred object has been resolve.

in `render`:

```
render: (template, context) ->
    dfd = $.Deferred()

    dust.render @template, context, (err, out) ->
        throw err if err
        done(out)
        dfd.resolve()

    return dfd;
```

You then take the method in Backbone.LayoutManager that calls render and instead of doing something with the return from render you attach that "something" to the `done` handler for the deferred you passed back.

```
    dfd = render(template, context)
    dfd.done(do_something_with_this_template);
```

I'm using Marionette.js (along with it's async variant) and dust, this is what my core `render` method looks like:

```
    render: function(){
        var dfd = $.Deferred();

        var template_context = this.model;
        if(_.isUndefined(template_context) || _.isFunction(template_context)){
            template_context = new (Backbone.Model.extend({}));
        }

        if(this.id) this.$el.attr('id', this.id);

        var that = this;
        dust.stream(this.tpl_name, template_context.toJSON())
            .on('data', function(data){
                that.$el.html(data);
            })
            .on('end', function(){
                dfd.resolve();
                that.enable_menus();
                that.trigger('template:rendered');
            })
            .on('error', function(err){
                dfd.reject();
                window.le(err.message, err);
                that.trigger('template:error');
            });

        return dfd;
    }
```

(Obviously not using coffeescript either...)